# Reference a TS interface from jsDoc

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

Using VSCode is almost possible to have the benefits from Typescript in plain `.js` thanks to jsDoc notation and a `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noEmit": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",

  },
  "include": ["index.js", "./src"]
}
```

```js
/**
 * @return {Promise<string>}
 */
const foo = Promise.resolve('hi');
module.exports = foo;
```

Now, **is it possible to reference an interface defined in a `d.ts` at `node_modules`**? in particular I'm returning a -let's call- "my_dependency.Storage" object but I'm unable to reference it using plain javascript:

```js
/**
 * @param {Storage} storage
 */
const goo = storage => ...
```

will understand that I'm refering to Web Storage API from `lib.dom.d.ts`

- The equivalent typescript would be:

```
import {Storage} from "my_dependency"
```

- I've tried using [triple slash directives](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html) unsuccessfully

```
///<reference path="node_modules/my_dependency/lib/index.d.ts" />
```

- I'm expecting something like (pseudo-code)

```js
/**
 * @param {my_module.Storage} storage
 */
```

Comment: In some cases the `import('firebase').app.App`, this is feature from TS 2.9. It might help your cause. I used it in my JS/TS project once.

Comment: @Akxe didn't get what you mention until now. This is exactly the syntax I was looking for. Thanks. Going to answer my own question with a piece of code

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As @Akxe mention this is how you can do this for referring a type from a lib:

```
/**
 * @param {import("my_dependency").Storage} storage
 */
const goo = storage => ...
```

Now, I found myself repeating that statement over and over again so I created an ambient alias as following:

***types.d.ts***

```
declare namespace MyProject {
  type St = import("my_dependency").Storage; // alias: reference my_dependency.Storage from plain js code
}
```

***index.js***

```
/// <reference path="types.d.ts"/>
...
```

***src/foo.js***

```
/**
 * @param {MyProject.St} storage
 */
const goo = storage => ...
```

---

==EDIT==

Here is [a post at dev.to that expands this topic](https://dev.to/manuartero/type-hints-on-pure-js-files-8ee)

Comment: I love the alias, where can I find more information?

Comment: I guess... [this doc maybe?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-2-9-rc/#import-types)

Comment: will typescript (or jsdoc) consumers of the package have MyProject as an ambient namespace automatically available?

Comment: @ricmed not sure TBH. Need to try it, if you happen to give that a try, please do post here the result !